# how to make video on portrait remain on its own area and when it will be tilted to horizontal it should go to full screen

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, jwplayer

I am using JW player javascript library. And now want to make it work in this way on mobile - when you are on portrait it needs to remain on its own are without playing with mobile default player, and when you change the orientation to landscape(horizontal) it should go to full screen automatically. So I want to do it like youtube. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read about javascript full screen API

Comment: You have to use the default mobile player as far as small iOS devices are concerned. It will always take over playback regardless.

Comment: On portrait I need when user click on play button video plays on its own area and not with mobile player, you mean there is no way to do this? @EthanJWPlayer

Comment: you mean that ? @Ethan JWPlayer

Comment: Not that I know of. On Apple devices (small ones), as soon as play is pressed, the full screen player takes over.

Comment: is there any way to change so it won't play with player but stay on its own area? @Ethan JWPlayer

Answer (score 3):

```
<video controls id="myvideo">
  <source src="somevideo.webm"></source>
  <source src="somevideo.mp4"></source>
</video>

$(window).on("orientationchange", function (event) {
  if (event.landscape) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
})
```

Use Fullscreen API on orientation change event and check if the mode is landscape :)

If your video is embedded in an iframe add the following attributes to your iframe--

```
<iframe … allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
```

Comment: my video is embedded as iframe @AkshayJ

Comment: and how I can do this - when you are on portrait it needs to remain on its own, I mean when you are on portrait video shouldn't play with phone player but play on its own are like on desktop. Any thoughts? @AkshayJ

Comment: Yes..Using HTML5 video tag you dont need to worry about external plugins or addons.Just embed a video tag in your html and it will use the browser plugins automatically :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of JW player, We can stream media, including video, to a MediaPlayer object using a surface view.
Step 1:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 2:
Extend Surface view in your MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener
```

Which overrides interface methods onSurfaceCreated, surfaceDestroyed, surfaceChanged, and onPrepared.

In the MainActivity's onCreate method, you can start to instantiate MediaPlayer & SurfaceHolder variables using the SurfaceView object you added to the layout:

```
    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);

    controller = new CustomMediaControllerView(this,true);
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(layoutVideoFrame);

    try {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(this, video);
        player.prepareAsync();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
       Log.e(TAG, "onCreate IllegalArgumentException:"+ex.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate SecurityException:" + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate IllegalStateException:" + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate IOException:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Step 3:
In SurfaceCreated method, We have to assign surface holder to Mediaplayer.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);       
}
```

In onPrepared override method, We can start player & show controller.

```
 @Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(isVideoLoaded) {
        isVideoPrepared=true;
        player.start();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        controller.show();
        player.seekTo((int) timeinterval);
    }
}
```

Step 4:
When user leave Activity, we have to handle Video play & pause from Activity lifecycle methods.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        player=null;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()){
        player.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /*if(!isVideoLoaded){
        isVideoPrepared=true;
    }*/
    if(player!=null && !player.isPlaying()){
        player.start();
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        player=null;
    }
}
```

So We have complete control over video, So i recommend to use custom media player implementation like this. Kindly share your view & give suggestion to improve this logic.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use orientationchange event of javascript:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){...})
```

You can check for "portrait" or "landscape" using:

```
event.portrait
event.landscape
```

By checking for landscape mode you can change the JW player properties dynamically to achieve full screen mode.